# Create sublists from a master list based on the first element of the list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the below List :

```
master_list =[['Apple','Red','Fresh','CA'],['Banana','Yellow','Fresh','NY'],['Mandarin','Orange','Fresh','WA'],['Apple','Red','Fresh','NJ'],['Banana','Yellow','Fresh','TX'],
['Apple','Red','Old','CA'],['Mandarin','Orange','Fresh','CA'],['Pineapple''Yellow','Fresh','MI']]
```

I need to loop through the above list and create separate lists based on the 0th element of each sublist in the master_list

The expected output is

```
l_apple=[['Apple','Red','Fresh','CA'],['Apple','Red','Fresh','NJ'],['Apple','Red','Old','CA']]
l_banana=[['Banana','Yellow','Fresh','TX'],['Banana','Yellow','Fresh','NY']]
l_mandarin=[['Mandarin','Orange','Fresh','WA'],['Mandarin','Orange','Fresh','CA']]
l_pineapple=[['Pineapple''Yellow','Fresh','MI']]"
```

i would really appreciate any suggestions or tips to code it in Python in an efficient manner.

Please note :We do not have a fixed list of fruits .So the number of lists that need to be generated might change based on the unique values(sourced from the first element of the list in the nested list) of fruits.
Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: And you got so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a dynamic number of fruits, you don't want to give each one a statically named variable.  Something like a dict is a better option:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> fruit_dict = defaultdict(list)
>>> for fruit in master_list:
...     fruit_dict[fruit[0]].append(fruit)
...
>>> dict(fruit_dict)
{
    'Apple': [['Apple', 'Red', 'Fresh', 'CA'], ['Apple', 'Red', 'Fresh', 'NJ'], ['Apple', 'Red', 'Old', 'CA']], 
    'Banana': [['Banana', 'Yellow', 'Fresh', 'NY'], ['Banana', 'Yellow', 'Fresh', 'TX']], 
    'Mandarin': [['Mandarin', 'Orange', 'Fresh', 'WA'], ['Mandarin', 'Orange', 'Fresh', 'CA']], 
    'PineappleYellow': [['PineappleYellow', 'Fresh', 'MI']]
}
```

Comment: Wow ..This solution is so much  better than what I was trying to do  .Than you so much for the quick help .

Answer (score 1):

As it was well said by Samwise, this is better approached by using a dictionary. But in case you really need to create those variables, and **if you are at module scope**, you can achieve this by doing the following:

```
master_list =[['Apple','Red','Fresh','CA'],['Banana','Yellow','Fresh','NY'],['Mandarin','Orange','Fresh','WA'],['Apple','Red','Fresh','NJ'],['Banana','Yellow','Fresh','TX'], ['Apple','Red','Old','CA'],['Mandarin','Orange','Fresh','CA'],['Pineapple','Yellow','Fresh','MI']]

for list_ in master_list:
    name = f'l_{list_[0].lower()}'
    vars().setdefault(name, []).append(list_)
```

**outputs**

```
>>> l_apple
[['Apple', 'Red', 'Fresh', 'CA'], ['Apple', 'Red', 'Fresh', 'NJ'], ['Apple', 'Red', 'Old', 'CA']]
>>> l_pineapple
[['Pineapple', 'Yellow', 'Fresh', 'MI']]
>>> l_mandarin
[['Mandarin', 'Orange', 'Fresh', 'WA'], ['Mandarin', 'Orange', 'Fresh', 'CA']]
>>> l_banana
[['Banana', 'Yellow', 'Fresh', 'NY'], ['Banana', 'Yellow', 'Fresh', 'TX']]
```

Comment: Thanks .This is the solution i was hoping for initially .But the post processing of teh data would be easier with a dictionary as SamWise Suggested

Comment: I agree. But I thought it was worth it mentioning it too.